# Issue on Getting Value of Input Text by Retun

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/g3oe601v/1/) and let me know why I am getting

> [object HTMLInputElement]

in return of the `nameInput()` function:

```
$(function () {
    var proceed = true;

    function nameInput(inputData) {
        inputData = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
       if (inputData == "") {
         alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
        }
        else{
            return inputData;
        }
    }

    $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
        if (nameInput(fname)){
            alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ fname);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: from you are getting `fname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3oe601v/7/)

`fname` is an object, and you need to access its value

Therefore, replace:

```
alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ fname);
```

by

```
alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ fname.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    if (nameInput(fname)){
        alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ fname);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ fname.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should not accept parameters but just return value of the textbox.

```
$("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
    var value = nameInput();
    if (value){
        alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ value);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And the function :

```
function nameInput() {
    inputData = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
   if (inputData == "") {
     alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
       return false;
    }
    else{
        return inputData;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g3oe601v/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If the value is not valid, you will have to return false indicating it is no valid.

```js
$(function () {
    var proceed = true;

    function nameInput(input) {
        var inputData = $.trim($('#' + input).val());
        if (inputData == "") {
            alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
            return false;
        } else {
            return inputData;
        }
    }

    $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
        var fname = nameInput('fname');
        if (fname !== false) {
            alert("The Field is Valid and Value is " + fname);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="pro" />
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`nameInput()` function you have update function argument `inputData` with input `selector` value..  and in this case function return reference on assigned value.. 
As you have used function argument in `alert()`,
You should use function return value, see below

```
$(function () {
    var proceed = true;

    function nameInput(inputData) {
        inputData = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
       if (inputData == "") {
         alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
        }
        else{
            return inputData;
        }
    }

    $("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
        var rfname = nameInput(fname);
        if (rfname){
            alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+ rfname);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

`$(function () {
    var proceed = true;

```
function nameInput() {
    inputData = $.trim($('input[type="text"]').val());
   if (inputData == "") {
     alert('Field Can Not be Empty');
    }
    else{
        return inputData;
    }
}

$("#pro").on("click", function (e) {
    var temp= nameInput();
    if (temp.length>0){
        alert("The Field is Valid and Value is "+temp);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});`